# Custom log in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat

I use software that makes logfiles in /var/log/*softwarename*/*YYYYMMDD*/
It uses JSON formatting. But I'm new to Kibana and have no idea how I can read out the log files properly, as I get the log files in a single rule while I should be able to use formatting.

This all sounds very vague, but please see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H6dCCw666Xw&t=341s (skip to 2:39). 
Hopefully this explains some things...

EDIT: Okay, I did some research and found out that it reads the correct files.
However formatting of it in Kibana is wrong:
https://puu.sh/vKyFO/0097ac2c0f.png
So how can I make sure it has proper fields and such, as in the video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please forget about the [grok filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html), instead used the [json filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html). It has the ability to parse json inputs. 
I have tried this configuration.

```
input {
  file {
       path => "/path/to/logfile/logfile"
  }
}

filter{
    json{
        source => "message"
    }
#remove message (not needed) 
    mutate {
      remove_field => ["message"]
    }
}


output {
     elasticsearch{
      hosts => ["elasticsearchip:9200"]
      manage_template => true
      index => "your-index"
    }
}
```

input

```
{"sessionend": "2017/05/09 14:20:44", "ver": "1", "host": "94.228.216.5", "session": "627650cf-a214-4c62-ba81-0eec6b9f57d3", "user": "(removedforsafety)", "timing": "2017/05/09 14:20:44", "sessionstart": "2017/05/09 14:20:34"}
```

Output in elasticsearch

```
{
    "_index" : "your-index",
    "_type" : "logs",
    "_id" : "AVvuH4v3tbMuoFZBfUAn",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "path" : "/path/to/logfile/logfile",
      "ver" : "1",
      "@timestamp" : "2017-05-09T16:51:36.156Z",
      "session" : "627650cf-a214-4c62-ba81-0eec6b9f57d3",
      "timing" : "2017/05/09 14:20:44",
      "@version" : "1",
      "host" : "94.228.216.5",
      "sessionend" : "2017/05/09 14:20:44",
      "user" : "(removedforsafety)",
      "sessionstart" : "2017/05/09 14:20:34"
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your help and thinking. The log files I have are shown in the print screen: https://puu.sh/vKyFO/0097ac2c0f.png
All log files I'd like to add to Kibana are stored like this. 
But I want for example for cmd, session etc a field in Kibana. 
I know you are correct, that it should be done with a filter, but unfortunately I just have no clue how... Perhaps you can give me a help in the right direction?

Comment: Ok, but what I want to see is a line of the logfiles in /var/log/softwarename/YYYYMMDD/.

Comment: Ok let me look at that.

Comment: Hi @berrytchaks, I've added the config file, but can't seem to add the Index to Kibana. I called the index "test" for well, testing purposes.
But even if I add a wildcard it still only finds the old index configuration?
There are no error logs in the logstash log file.


EDIT: Could it have something to do with that I have Filebeat running as well?

Comment: Can you see the index on elasticsearch? Used this command to find out curl -XGET 'elasticsearchIp:9200/_cat/indices?v'